# Angular with Angular Material - MatTable(s) with multiple MatTab(s)

Tags: angular, angular-material

Newbie question. I have an Angular `Component` which display data separated by a specific field on multiple tabs, using tables.

Say the data model is:

```
company {
   type: "...",
   country: "...",
   name: "..."
}
```

and the data is separated on multiple tabs by `type`.
It is also possible to filter this data, and that filter should affect data displayed in every tab.
Here it is a poor mockup.

[image]

What's the best approach to accomplish this?
Is a new table per tab too much? Should I just create a single table and refresh the data displayed on every tab change `(+)` filter update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way material tabs work, they have a unique content body container for each tab by design, so that the content can transition on tab change.

- Unfortunately, I think you have no choice but to generate a mat-table for each tab because of this.
- I could be wrong and there may be a way to do it that I am not familiar with, in which case I will delete this answer.

Comment: Maybe the tabs should just `@Output()` an event on change. Using that event I could update the only instance of the MatTable. So the MatTab(s) would have no content, they would be there just to emit the "change" event, containing the Type ID.

Comment: It sounds like you would essentially have the MatTable outside the scope of the MatTabs content body, not physically in the body of the MatTab. If I understand correctly you would essentially be using the MatTab as a glorified event emitter... which is doable... but defeats the purpose of using the MatTab component in my opinion. In this case, I would personally explore coming up with my own html tabs solution to have full control over the content of my page while avoiding any issues from customizing the intended use of the MatTab component. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: A custom solution may be better, and lightweight. I might go with Bootstrap Material tabs and handle the `click` event, on each. But even with this solution the MatTable would be outside the tabs. Have I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: No I think you are correct in your understanding. The difference in the example link I provided is that you essentially don't need to use the tab content piece in the html, you could just use the tabs to trigger your event which would update the content body/MatTable in your page... you would essentially have no tab content body in this example, only the page content body containing one MatTable.

Comment: I think that's doable. I will wait for other answers, as maybe it can be solved in a more efficient way. Thanks ;)

Comment: No problem, I will definitely remove if that is the case.

Comment: I honestly thought Angular was quite popular. Not many views as of now.

Comment: It is, may take a few days for people to take interest why answer has not been accepted.

Comment: Just following up to see if this answer helped you identify a solution?